# ROS / RoboEarth Package WIRE - unable to get source. Fuerte

Tags: ros, svn, roboearth

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am attempting to install the WIRE stack, as described on http://wiki.ros.org/wire  however, when I try to run

> svn co https://robotics.wtb.tue.nl/svn/ros/release/wire

I just get the response

> svn: access to 'https://robotics.wtb.tue.nl/svn/ros/release/wire' forbidden

Could anyone explain how to get access to this?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/150236/ros-/-roboearth-package-wire---unable-to-get-source.-fuerte/) by [rmb209](https://answers.ros.org/users/14126/rmb209/) on ROS Answers with karma: 80 on 2014-04-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This has now been updated -  question Closed.

The SVN link is https://roboticssrv.wtb.tue.nl/svn/ros/release/wire/

---

Originally posted by [rmb209](https://answers.ros.org/users/14126/rmb209/) with karma: 80 on 2014-04-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You should try sending the authors an email notifying them of the problem: http://www.tue.nl/en/employee/ep/e/d/ep-uid/20117761/ep-tab/4/

---

Originally posted by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) with karma: 11816 on 2014-04-10

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [rmb209](https://answers.ros.org/users/14126/rmb209/) on 2014-04-11**:
I have emailed both and hopefully there will be a response shortly. I will endeavour to update this post when I hear back.